# Xamarin (Visual Studio) x POSTGRESQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, visual-studio, xamarin

Boa noite pessoal, 
Trabalho em uma empresa de desenvolvimento de softwares de automação comercial, A Alterdata, e hoje trabalho diretamente com o PostgreSql, e tenho muita afinidade com ele.

Gostaria de saber se tenho como sincronizar o Postgres com o Visual Studio ( Xamarin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer trabalhar com o PostgreSQL diretamente na aplicação mobile, a resposta é não. Você não tem como instalar o PostgreSQL no Android, iOS ou winPhone. Para isso você tem o SQLite.

Se você quer conectar a uma base remota, é possível, porém não recomendado. Conforme vi aqui: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29034/connect-to-postgresql você precisaria de uma biblioteca que suporte as plataformas mobile.

O ideal nesse caso, seria webservice ou webApi.

Outra discussão: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/53795/postgres-sql-database-connectivity

Answer (score 0):

É possível utilizar sim o Postgresql em projetos no Visual Studio, independente da linguagem ou framework que estiver utilizando (já utilizei com o Entity, por exemplo).

A conexão será similar as de SQLServer, você apenas irá alterar o Data Provider para o Npgsql, que é o ADO.NET Provider específico para conexões com Postgresql.

Segue o link com mais instruções: http://www.npgsql.org/